# AngularJs not hiding html directives on Production / Release

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a problem with Angularjs HTML directives on production, Which is I want to hide these directives when i publish / release my project but I couldn't do it. For you to understand better the problem, please see the image below;

[image: Image about Problem]

What I have tried so far;

```
app.config(['$compileProvider', function ($compileProvider) {
    $compileProvider.debugInfoEnabled(false);
    $compileProvider.commentDirectivesEnabled(false);
    $compileProvider.cssClassDirectivesEnabled(false);
}]);
```

But the code above didn't fix my problem, Do you have any idea about this ?

My AngularJS version is 1.6.9

Comment: Do you mean hide the attribute from displaying in the inspector?

Comment: Yes exactly, as you can see in the picture i don't want those attribues be seen on production

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to hide attribute directives in AngularJS .

`$compileProvider.debugInfoEnabled(false);`

Will prevent angular from rendering debug information such as placeholder comments for structural directives. You can read more about that here: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/production

`$compileProvider.commentDirectivesEnabled(false);`

Will disable the use of deprecated comment directives like `<!-- directive: my-dir exp -->` You can read about that here: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Class directives are also explained on that page and can be turned off by the use of `$compileProvider.cssClassDirectivesEnabled(false);`

Comment: Thanks for you interest so i have to show ng-repeat and etc to anyone. It is not so important but i would like to hide them if i can.